# How can I divide cases in viewWillAppea by Segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, appdelegate, viewwillappear

## Purpose

I am making App to see a 3D model by Scene kit.
Swift 4.0
Xcode 10.1

I want to transfer the image. I create a image in SCNViewController (using SCN View) and after that move to ViewController.
I want to divide cases when I transfer a image.
I think it is better to use a Segue.

[image]
Segue detail
[image]

**Array**
I use a array in AppDelegate. Because I want to add and add a image in ViewController. I don't wand erase a image when I move to other ViewController.

## Problems

When I write like below it will crush.I use a func viewWillAppear.

ViewController

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if appDelegate.isNewSCNStampAdded == true{
             let scnstamp = appDelegate.scnstampArray.last!

             func returnToTop(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
                 if segue.identifier == "backtoFirstcoma" {
                 mainImageView.image = scnstamp
                 mainImageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
                 print("1")
             }else if segue.identifier == "backtoSecondcoma" {
                 print("2")
             }else if segue.identifier == "backtoThirdcoma" {
                 print("3")
             }else {
                 print("others")
             }
        }
        appDelegate.isNewSCNStampAdded = false
    }
}
```

**(2nd idea)**

I tried another way. I made a "dividegoes" to distinguish. But this way is also not work. I can't catch a info of "dividegoes" in the timing of viewWillAppear.
ViewController

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if appDelegate.isNewSCNStampAdded == true{
             let scnstamp = appDelegate.scnstampArray.last!

             switch dividegoes {
             case "goone" :
                 mainImageView.image = scnstamp
                 print("1")
             case "gotwo" :
                 secondImageView.image = scnstamp
                 print("2")
             case "gothree" :
                 thirdImageView.image = scnstamp
                 print("3")
             default:
                 print("Others")
             }
        }
        appDelegate.isNewSCNStampAdded = false
    }
}
```

SCNViewController

```
let dividegoes = "gozero"

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "backtoFirstcoma" :
        let whiteVc = segue.destination as! ViewController
        whiteVc.dividegoes = "goone"
        print("go1")
    case "backtoSecondcoma" :
        let blueVc = segue.destination as! ViewController
        blueVc.dividegoes = "gotwo"
        print("go2")
    case "backtoThirdcoma" :
        let greenVc = segue.destination as! ViewController
        greenVc.dividegoes = "gothree"
        print("go3")
    default:
        print(“Others")
    }
}
```

How can I divide cases in this case.
If I erase a "if-else" structure, it work successful. But I need divide in 3 ways.

**Error Message**
whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

## My idea

I couldn't use a Segue in viewWillAppear...?
Maybe I need to use other way to divide cases...

Comment: first, don't compare bool in if condition `if appDelegate.isNewVRMStampAdded == true {`. simplified -> `if appDelegate.isNewVRMStampAdded { `

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

You should consider using this func rather than `viewWillAppear` mate.

Comment: In 2nd way, I tried to use "func prepare" in VRMViewController like below.
(I add a explain my article)

Comment: Could you provide some more detail mate? Like how you present `VRMViewController ` (push or performSegue). And what's the connection between `ViewController ` and `VRMViewController`

Comment: All Segue is Present Modally.
I add a image of detail.

Comment: Could you show the code how `VRMViewController ` show `ViewController `?. (The storyboard relationship is fine)

Comment: I connect to ViewController using func saveImage. I add a code.

Comment: Okay, I found one problem is `appDelegate.isNewVRMStampAdded = false ` from `viewWillAppear `. Once you set it to false it never been set back to true again. Which lead to that logic `switch dividegoes {` never executed.

Comment: mmmmm... Maybe I think appDelegate.isNewVRMStampAdded = true in "func saveImage". When I push a button return to true again...

Comment: Maybe switch logic is bad as you mentioned... I am trying to correct define of "dividegoes"...